# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "client_apps_externalkeys" does not exist

Tags: django

I was trying to save stripe api keys to db and use, managed to save the keys to db, but when I call it in views getting the above error. How I can call it in views without this error, what I tried is follows

```
class ExternalKeys(models.Model):
    public = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True, null=True)
    secret = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True, null=True)
    webhook_secret = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True, null=True
```

and when I call it in views `stripe.api_key = str(ExternalKeys.objects.first().public)` instead of normal way `stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY` getting the above error, is there any other way of storing api keys so that the client can edit it in future without the help of developer
[image]

Comment: Can you please show your views.py

Answer (score 1):

you should try to create a new DB & re-run the make migrations & migrate command. It seems the relation you tried to set through django ORM, they do not exist in real db.